# Is there still prophecy among the gentiles?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, gentiles

I would like to know if there is currently, or has every been since the times of Bilaam a genuine prophet among the gentile nations. Meaning, someone who was not Jewish and whose prophecy was only for the benefit of non-Jews but was recognized by orthodox Rabbis as a prophet.

Furthermore I would like to know what qualifications a person must present in order to be considered by Jewish law a prophet for the non-Jews. Meaning, does the person have to meet the same criteria as that of a prophet for the Jews or are there other criteria? If it is the latter, what are they?

Comment: See my answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121291/any-pre-7th-century-jewish-source-teaches-that-non-jewish-prophets-will-never-b/121498#121498

Answer (score 8):

The Medrash (Tanchuma 1, cited by [Rashi Bamidbar 22:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9950/jewish/Chapter-22.htm#showrashi=true)) says that Bilaam was only given prophecy to quiet a possible argument of the non-Jews that they were never given a prophet.  This implies that there really is no other purpose of non-Jewish prophecy, and therefore there would not be such a thing.

There is no practical ramifications to Jewish law about whether or not a non-Jew is an authentic prophet (even if there could be such a thing) and therefore there would be no reason for Jewish law to have standards for recognizing it.  A non-Jewish prophet could not add new Noahide laws any more than a Jewish one could.

Comment: Abraham existed before Israel and Jacob and Judah amd Moses were born and before Torah was revealed. Thus, is technically a "Gentile Prophet".