# Any pre 7th century Jewish source, teaches that non-Jewish prophets will never be sent again?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, torah-study, midrash, mishna

1- were the non-Jewish prophets sent to non-Jewish nations only, and not Jews ? if the answer is Yes
Does it mean there is no way a non-Jewish prophet can ever be sent to the Jews? any textual basis for that?

Any pre 7th century Jewish source, that teach that non-Jewish prophets will never be sent again?

thanx

Comment: There is no limit placed on prophecy to non-Jews.

Answer (score 8):

From the Talmud, tractate Brachot, 7a: (450-550 CE)

> And Rabbi Yoḥanan said in the name of Rabbi Yosei regarding Moses’ request that the Divine Presence rest upon Israel as it once had: **Moses requested three things from the Holy One, Blessed be He, at that time, all of which were granted him**. He requested that the Divine Presence rest upon Israel and not leave, and He granted it to him, as it is stated: “For how can it be known that I have found grace in Your sight, I and Your people? Is it not in that You go with us, so that we are distinguished, I and Your people, from all the people that are on the face of the earth?” (Exodus 33:16). The request: Is it not in that You go with us, refers to the resting of the Divine Presence upon Israel. **Moses requested that the Divine Presence not rest upon the nations of the world, and He granted it to him, as it is stated: “So that we are distinguished, I and Your people, from all the people on the face of the earth” (Exodus 33:16).** Lastly, Moses requested that the ways in which God conducts the world be revealed to him, and He granted it to him, as it is stated: “Show me Your ways and I will know You” (Exodus 33:13).

Answer (score 2):

An even better source than the one in my first answer is the verse of Deuteronomy ch. 18 v. 15:

> נָבִ֨יא מִקִּרְבְּךָ֤ מֵאַחֶ֙יךָ֙ כָּמֹ֔נִי יָקִ֥ים לְךָ֖ יְהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ אֵלָ֖יו תִּשְׁמָעֽוּן׃
> A prophet from your midst, of your brethren, like me, will Adonoy, your God, establish for you; heed him.

According to the Midrashic Biblical commentary known as Sifrei (approx. 200 BCE) this teaches that Jews should not heed prophets from the non-Jews:

> A prophet from your midst, from your brothers, such as I, the L-rd your G-d will establish for you": "from your midst" — not from outside Eretz Yisrael; "from your brothers" — not from others (i.e., gentiles). "will establish for you" — and not for idolators. How, then, am I to understand (Jeremiah 1:5) "A prophet for the nations have I made you (Jeremiah)"? For those (Jews) who deport themselves as the nations do.

Comment: Thanx N.T  for the  helpful answer... which raised in my mind another question  related :Bil'am was a non-Jew prophet, his prophecy is about Israel mainly and is integral part of Pentateuch... If Bilaam's prophecy (Num 23, 24), contained much pertaining to Israel, and may have been his only prophetic experience (Nahmanides on Num 22:31)., can we include him (though gentile)  as one of the fulfillments of  Deuteronomy ch. 18 v. 15?  if  not why not?

Comment: No, for two reasons. A: He prophesied about the Jews, not to them. B: The events of Bilaam happened before Moses spoke in Deuteronomy.